# Python run shortcut in GEdit

Tags: python, ubuntu, gedit

I'd like a shortcut key for GEdit that will run the currently open .py file when I press, say, F5. I have a script that does this via an external Terminal window, but I'm having more trouble creating a version that uses the internal output window (Shell Output, I guess), since I can't find a good way to grab the pyenv details from the ~./bashrc file. Working with pyenv is mandatory.

Here's what I have via GEdit's External Tools plugin:

**UNSOLVED: Internal Shell Output method:**

I wanted to get access to the pyenv settings in ~./bashrc, so I tried this External Tools script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +m
bash -i python $GEDIT_DOCUMENTS_PATH
```

This works (thanks to -i), but it gives me the "bash: no job control in this shell" warning. Running **set +m** should get rid of this message, but it doesn't.

So I moved the relevant stuff I had at the end of ~/.bashrc over to this script, which is not ideal at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.pyenv"
if [ -d "${PYENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

export PYENV_VERSION=3.3.4
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.pyenv/versions/3.3.4/lib/python3.3/site-packages/PySide-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/PySide/
python $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME
```

Problems: This last block is terrible. It's just copied from ~/.bashrc, and it even has to include PySide data that ~/.bashrc should take care of. Also, for some reason, using this method always outputs the first line of the .py file (say, *import sys*). Obviously, no input() can be given using this method, and outputting to GEdit's Embedded Terminal seems impossible. Also, I can't get rid of the "Done" message, even by using **set +m** or running the command in a subshell.

**SOLVED: External Terminal window method:**

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal -x $SHELL -ic "python $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME; printf \"\nPress any key to continue.\"; read -n 1 -s"
```

or, define a Terminal profile called, say, Wait, that sets Title and Command->When terminal exits: Hold the terminal open, and do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-terminal --profile=Wait -x $SHELL -ic "python $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME; printf \"\nPress any key to continue.\""
```

This gives a "status 0" message though, so the other method is better. Both methods use an interactive shell to access ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Have you considered using [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com)? While not F/OSS, it has several ways of running Python files, including the ability to generate multiple "build systems" for different versions/virtualenvs, and the [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) plugin lets you run one or more Python interpreters within the editor itself.

Answer (score 6):

Steps to add your custom shortcut key and functionality in GEdit:

1) Open the Manage External Tools.

2) Add a tool

3) Give the tool a name.

4) Enter this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
python $GEDIT_DOCUMENTS_PATH
```

5) Give Shortcut Key as F5 by typing directly the function key <kbd>F5</kbd> into the box.

To run the current file, you should save it first. You can now see the output in `Shell Output` window that comes up when you run the command either through <kbd>F5</kbd> or manually clicking on the command.

Of course, you can modify it to suit your own needs.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I ended up having a lot more trouble than expected making this work with pyenv, so I've edited the original question to include more detail about the current status of the script.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same. After reading your post the answers and comments, I tried myself around.

To run only the currently open document, open (I am using gedit under Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS) under
Tools>Manage External Tools pressing '+' to add a new tool:
and type in into the screen for the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# run the current document in python
python $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_PATH
```

The $GEDIT_DOCUMENTS_PATH would apply it to all folders in your current folder of your document - but you wanted to run only the current document isn't it? And the other suggestions: I don't understand why one should make it unnecessarily complicated and why one should ask again - because the moment you press the key you want that thing to be executed, isn't it?

I tried it myself and it works flawlessly.